# How to restart a loop if the input is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python. I'm trying to code a basic hangman game, the thing is, when I put on purpuse a wrong answer, my for loop keep making the iteration as if nothing happen, I'd like that each time I mistake, the loop "freeze" o keep in the same letter until I put the correct answer.

This is my code:

```
word = input("Introduce a word ")

n = len(word)
print("The word has "+ str(n) + " letters")
print("Hint: The first letter is " + word[0])
print("")

for i in word:
    print(i)
    if i == input("Guess the letter: "):
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong !")
```

Comment: You never use `tries`...

Comment: You right, indeed, I deleted because, it didn't have any sense. For now I don't care about tries.

Comment: I assume the `print(i)` is for debugging purposes?

Comment: Exactly ! , Just to make sure I'm doing the things right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop forever and break from the loop if the answer is correct.

```
for character in word:
    print(character)
    while True:
        if character == input("Guess the letter: "):
            print("Correct")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong !")
```

The `while` part of the code in real world language: "I'm going to ask you forever until you give me the correct answer."

Comment: Thanks you, and thanks to everybody that took a little time to answer this little and silly question ! I have a lot to learn, but I'm motivated thanks for current comunity :)

Comment: Oh no, that was not a silly question if you're new. Over the time you'll see that a `while True` loop is used quite often in Python code.